# my list dont work keeping saying warrants not defined

Tags: python, list

```
names=[ 
    ["Scott Walters","W12345",11],
    ["Rishi Goomar","G67890",8],
    ["Chris Flading","F45678",2],
    ["Chris Dearnley","D23456",10],
    ["Nick Smetana","S90123",5],
    ["Lukasz Morysewicz","M78901",15],
    ["Sravya Boddu","B34567",7],
    ["John Venderley","V56789",4]
    ]

for i in names:
         i= names, license, warrants
         print names[i],license[i],warrants[i]
```

Why is this not working?
it keep says warrants not defined which it should be i

Answer (score 0):

Flip your statement. Your assignment is backwards:

```
i= names, license, warrants
```

Should be

```
names, license, warrants = i
print names,license,warrants
```

This will output:

```
Scott Walters W12345 11
Rishi Goomar G67890 8
Chris Flading F45678 2
Chris Dearnley D23456 10
Nick Smetana S90123 5
Lukasz Morysewicz M78901 15
Sravya Boddu B34567 7
John Venderley V56789 4
```

A good tutorial to look at for further help is from [Dive Into Python](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/odbchelper_multiassign.html), covering assigning multiple values at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use unpacking.

```
for i in names:
    names, license, warrants = i # for first time i = ['Scott Walters', 'W12345', 11]
    print names, license, warrents
```

here

```
i[0] = names, i[1] = license, i[2] = warrents
```